# Symfony / Messenger consume specific queue

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

I'm trying to send messages from a specific queue from messenger with Symfony, but I get the error that says that I have not implemented "QueueReceiverInterface", except that on the Symfony doc there is no example... do you know how we do it?

https://symfony.com/doc/5.x/messenger.html#limit-consuming-to-specific-queues

Thanks

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using, and what message-transport have you configured?

Comment: my version of Symfony is 5.4, and the doctrine transport